# Parse Error T_CLASS

Tags: php, parse-error

I am trying to write a class for users of my site to login, I haven't gotten very far and am already getting errors.

```
<?php 

    function isIn () {
        if(isset($_SESSION) && $_SESSION['signed_in'] == TRUE) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    class User {
        public function post($db) {
        }

        public function LoginForm() { //says problem is on this line
            echo '<form  method="post">
                <div id="textbox">
                    <input type="text" id="username"     name="username" value="Username:" maxlength="100" size="16" onfocus="changeUsername();"/>
            </div>
            <div id="passbox">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="Password:" maxlength="20" size="16"/>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" value="TRUE"name="login"/>
            <input type="submit" id="login" value="" />
        </form>
        <p id="loginlinks"><a href="forgotpass.php">Forgot Password</a> / <a href="register.php">Register</a></p>
        </div>';
    }

    public function Login(){}

}
```

The error is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\WhyImEvil\WIP\member.php on line 15`. I am running PHP Version 5.3.5.

For the life of my I can't figure this out.

Here is the code that includes the file:

```
<?php
require_once('database.php');
require_once('member.php');
session_start();
$signedIn=isIn();

$person;
$dbc;

if(!signedIn) {
    $person=new User();
    $dbc=new Database();
}

$dbc->connect();
?>
```

Comment: Also when I access member.php directly there is no error. Only when I go to the main page where it is included.

Comment: Works fine. http://codepad.org/hNfgD62y You may have a null-character in there somewhere which is messing things up. Use an editor which can show invisible characters to check.

Comment: I'm using notepad++, this should show invisible character right?

Comment: How do you include it? The code from above itself throws no errors.

Comment: You have to reference here file from witch you do include and perform class init. This code is perfectly fine.

Comment: @EricLarsen see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849115/109302

Comment: @djot Added the code for posting

Comment: @nikc nothing seems out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you making a call to public function LoginForm() with a public function LoginForm(STRING)???
(always take off line wrap and make sure that the line matches... sometimes another line can get the blame.)