# How to search for symbol like DC1 in Notepad++

Tags: xml, ascii

How to search for special ascii characters( like symbol 'DC1') in a file using notepad ++ or any text editors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution atlast .

The Ascii character equivalent for DC1 symbol is x11,

In the extended mode in notepad++ find, giving '\x11' should help you in finding the character.

For the list of ascii characters and their code, please find the link below

http://ascii.cl/

Answer (score 7):

**Notepad++:**

Enable showing all hidden characters. **View->Show all characters**

Or enable hex mode using **ctrl-h** and look/search for 11

**References:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Control_1#Device_Control

[Does notepad++ show all hidden characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767545/does-notepad-show-all-hidden-characters)