# menu is not showing in html page

Tags: jquery, css

Created one jquery menu but it's working only in fiddle but not working in html page which i made [Html menu page link](http://www.creativecorp.in/guru/test.html)

here is the which is working now in fiddle

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/RHVDT/32/)

way to reproduce when mouseover on Homepage link one submenu will be show, next mouseover on one link in submenu multi submenu show.

also appreciate if place a small arrow for right side of one link.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code. Do you use debugging tools when you are developing?

Comment: May I suggest you check out JQuery Mobile?

Comment: yes you are right but how do i solve..

Comment: are u using the same jquery versions?

Answer (score 3):

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
http://www.creativecorp.in/guru/test.html
Line 19
```

Looks like you have some hidden control character in your code after the semicolon. Use an editor that allows you to see all of the [hidden characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767545/does-notepad-show-all-hidden-characters).