# Assembly, syntax error

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, masm

```
name lab2

data segment
podatak1 dw 1
rezultat dw 0
data ends

code segment
assume cs:code, ds:data

start: 

    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov ax, podatak1
    add ax, cx
    mov rezultat, ax


    code ends
end start
end
```

i get syntax error, all the time?
Does anyone know the solution? thanks!
btw, i use masm 6.5

Comment: Please specify the exact error messages you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
mov ax, data
```

to

```
mov ax, @data
```

Apart from that, it would be helpfull to post the exact errors you get.

Comment: lab2.asm(1) : error 10: Syntax error
lab2.asm(17) : error 9: Symbol not defined @DATA

this is what i get when i add @

Comment: Remove the `@` I was confusing it with some other problem. where did you get masm 6.5 from? I'm using the MASM32 download and this include MASM 6.14, and this assembles fine. I can't find a reference to a 6.5 version either.

Comment: i got it from my teacher, idk. :) it goes with CodeView too. i downloaded it from my faculty site.

Comment: Codeview is an old 16 bit debugger. When I look for this, it references either the masm32 download (which I use and is 6.14) or even older masm's, but no 6.5 version. Are you sure about that, or can you provide the download link?

Comment: The download link is at my faculty department's locked VIP access only site.

Comment: You could remove (or put a ';' in front) at the first line, as the sytnax error seems to be from there (name lab2). I just don't see why it works here.

Comment: Still have syntax error even when i put commentary commas ; ... idk what is wrong with this. :/

Comment: Maybe you have some hidden characters in your sourcefile? What you could try is to create a backup, then copy the text from the above posting and paste it into a brand new textfile and assemble it. I copied your code into a file here and it definitely assembles without errors.

Comment: Damn, it is working now. Do you have some documentary about those hidden characters in sourcefiles and can you tell me something more about that?

Comment: I asumme that you maybe introduced some invisible characters like CTRL+something or such. When yopu posted it here, these characters were removed, so it worked for me. You can look at the textfile with a hex editor and try to find out where it is, if you want. Some editors may show them, but it seems yours is simply hiding it. I would expect the offending char in the first line already.

Comment: Well, mostly i use EDIT from CMD but know (for a change) i used Notepad++, it has good color highlight thingy for every program language. Guess he is one evil text editor. thanks again.

Comment: NP++ ias a good editor, I use it also for many purposes (just not for coding :p) About the hidden characters you can look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767545/does-notepad-show-all-hidden-characters