# Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions

Tags: matlab

I have an error when I try to run this on Matlab r2012b

```
t=-2:.1:5;
x=3*exp(0.4*t);
y=2*exp(-0.9*t);
plot(t,x,t,y,':');
legend('x(t)','y(t)')
```

Yielding the error:

```
>> t=-2:.1:5;
 t=-2:.1:5;
   |
Error: The input character is not
valid in MATLAB statements or
expressions.
```

---

*Editors note:*

First code line of original post contained a "hidden" character (single source of error) which was, due to SO formatting, lost in the first edit (intended to fix code formatting). Even when re-rolling back to revision 1, the "hidden" character is lost.

> t=**{Character: ASCII Code 2}**-2:.1:5;

Original code (thanks Daniel) can be found here

- http://pastebin.com/SyEHKpjR

Comment: @dfri I would recommend explicitly calling out the ASCII character you removed in your edit, since it's what is causing the error

Comment: @excaza Ow, my bad, didn't realize I removed the part of interest. I'm still a bit unsure what part I messed up, could you possibly fix this with an edit, or should I just backroll to rev1? Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I tried to fix the question SO seems to filter these special chars. I had to copy it directly from the source code of the question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Daniel Seems like I didn't explicitly remove it, but that the SO code formatting did? I'm confused, as I can find it in the raw source of rev1 but not rev2.

Comment: The original code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/SyEHKpjR . I am unable to get any useful formatting for this question.

Comment: My apologies for messing up the original post w.r.t. the single part of interest; I've tried to redeem it with the editors note above, but haven't been able to re-introduce the original _start of text_ character, not even by roll-back to revision 1.

Comment: thanks all for helping me out of this :) really helpful

Comment: @dfri: I knew what I was searching, I used the [source view](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/ae792bf1-fa4a-4f03-aff9-e5ddc8e8f227/view-source) of the question instead of trying to format it. In the rendered version it was not available as well, that's why a roll-back did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code the third char of `t=-2:.1:5;` is not a whitespace (ASCII Code 32) like MATLAB displays it,  it is a [start of text (ASCII Code 2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#STX). I have no idea how these control chars got into your code, but to clean it up I recommend a text editor which allows [to display all hidden chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767545/does-notepad-show-all-hidden-characters).

Comment: damn it was a "space" between t= -2. Now i get it, it Works!! thanks

Comment: nice one! I copied the code and could not recreate it, didn't realize it could have been a special char in there.

Comment: @GameOfThrows: In the [original version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/ae792bf1-fa4a-4f03-aff9-e5ddc8e8f227/view-source) of the question you can clearly see the `|` pointing to the problem. Then I knew what I was searching.