# Tricky list manipulation inside a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following data in a file. I want to extract the `time` and the `size` from relevant lines and plot a timeseries graph.

```
    03/12 20:23:26.11: 04:23:26 L9 <Mx  Acc  Magnum All            XDV:00111A0000000117 00D3001200870172 01FF6000F01CFE81 3D26000000000300
    03/12 20:23:26.11: 04:23:26 L9 <Mx  Acc  MID 0x1500 Len 26   XDV:00111A0000000117 00D3001200870172 01FF6000F01CFE81 3D26000000000300
    03/12 20:23:26.11: 04:23:26 L8 <Mx  JK31 (Mx)                  JSP:17.37.6.99: Size = 166, Data: 00345C4101003031 E463EF0113108701 5A01FF6008F01CFE 81AB170000000003 EF01131087015A01 FF6008F01CFE81AB 170000000003EF01 131087015B01FF60 00F01CFE81701B00 00000003EF011310 87015B01FF6000F0 1CFE81701B000000 0003EF0113108701 5C01FF2000F01CFE 81CB240000000003 EF01131087015C01 57CC00F01CFE81CB 240000000003EF01 131087015D01FF20 00F01CFE815B2900 00000003EF011310 87015D01FF2000F0 1CFE815B29000000 0003EF0113108701 5E01FF6000F01CFE 819D280000000003 EF01131087015E01 FF6000F01CFE819D 0003
    03/15 20:23:26.11: 04:23:26 L8 <Kx  JK31 (Kx)                  JSP:15.33.2.93: Size = 163, Data: 00647741000030EF 01131087015A01FF 6008F01CFE81AB17 0000000003EF0113 1087015A01FF6008 F01CFE81AB170000 000003EF01131087 015B01FF6000F01C FE81701B00000000 03EF01131087015B 01FF6000F01CFE81 701B0000000003EF 01131087015C01FF 2000F01CFE81CB24 0000000003EF0113 1087015C01FF2000 F01CFE81CB240000 000003EF01131087 015D01FF2000F01C FE815B2900000000 03EF01131087015D 01FF2000F01CFE81 5B290000000003EF 01131087015E01FF 6000F01CFE819D28 0000000003EF0113 1087015E01FF6000 F01CFE819D280000 A6220000000003
    03/15 20:23:26.11: 04:23:26 L9 <Kx  JK31 (Kx)                  JSP:10.22.1.53:Size = 163, Data: 009D1141000030EF 01131087015A01FF 6008F01CFE81AB17 0000000003EF0113 1087015A01FF6008 F01CFE81AB170000 000003EF01131087 015B01FF6000F01C FE81701B00000000 03EF01131087015B 01FF6000F01CFE81 701B0000000003EF 01131087015C01FF 2000F01CFE81CB24 0000000003EF0113 1087015C01FF2000 F01CFE81CB240000 000003EF01131087 015D01FF2000F01C FE815B2900000000 03EF01131087015D 01FF2000F01CFE81 5B290000000003EF 01131087015E01FF 6000F01CFE819D28 0000000003EF0113 1087015E01FF6000 F01CFE819D280000 A6220000000003
```

I have the following program to do it.

```
from dateutil import parser

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

match_list = ["L8 <Mx JK31 (Mx)", "L9 <Mx JK31 (Mx)"]  ## put all match strings in this list
with open("test.txt") as fin:
    print(' : {}', fin.name)
    time_data = {}  ## save data in dictionaries, with string keys and lists as values
    size_data = {}
    for line in fin:
        for match in match_list:
            if match in line:
               if match not in time_data:
                   time_data[match] = []  ## initialize empty list the first time this key is encountered
                   size_data[match] = []
               line = line.strip.split()
               time_str = line[2]
               t = parser.parse(time_str)  
               time_data[match].append(t)
               size = int(line[9].strip(","))
               size_data[match].append(size)


    for match in match_list:
        plt.figure()  ## create a new figure for each data set
        plt.plot(time_data[match], size_data[match])
    plot.show()  ## simultaneously show all plots
```

I am using two dictionaries above, `time_data` and `size_data`. Each of the data contains the elements of `match_list` as their key. The `values` are a list that contains datetime objects.

The above was done so that it would be easy to plot using matplotlib. 
Now I want to do the following.

As you can see in the sample data above for the same key `L8 <Mx JK31 (Mx)` you have two values that has the same time (`04:23:26`).

I want to modify the data structure (i.e the list inside my dictionaries) in such a way that I want the size values (i.e values in the list inside dictionary `size_data`) to be summed up every minute.

Suppose there are 5 values as below

04:23:26   56
04:23:26   60
04:23:43   70
04:23:46   80
04:23:56   90

I want the above to be replace with `04:23:00` and `356`. How do I go about doing this.

Comment: Does the file by any chance contain only tab separated values? If so, use the `csv` module.

Comment: @ReutSharabani - I don't think so.It does seem to contain spaces.

Comment: Spaces are there inside values, but what separates **values**?

Comment: @ReutSharabani - I am not sure. How do I check?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767545/does-notepad-show-all-hidden-characters

Comment: @ReutSharabani - That is not the case

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is a bit easier than it seems at first, because the extra overhead of the parsing of the file. I assume that the parsing works, and you end up with a list tuples, dicts... 
Now you want to perform an kind of aggregation on that list, right?

so, starting from

```
[
['10:10:01', 45],
['10:10:11', 135],
['10:10:50', 21],
['10:10:57', 4],
['10:11:01', 2],
['10:11:11', 8]
]
```

you want to get

```
[
['10:10:00', 205],
['10:11:00' 10]
]
```

if so, you could easily use a defaultdict and datetime.replace(seconds=0) for that.

This code is not be plug-and-play, but you should be able to fit it into your situation quite easily

```
input = # your parser function
output = defaultdict(int)

for date, value in input.items():
  output[date.replace(seconds=0)] += value
```

If you want a list again you could use `output.items()`

Good Luck!

Comment: My list isn't like this. I mean, I have two separate lists in two dictionaries. They are related by a common `key`