# Combine Rows to One in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

i try

> \r\n----------
>
> with
>
> replace :

not works for me

Example:
https://i.imgsafe.org/247208542e.png

i need

> bitte:dream

whats the right regex way?

Comment: Maybe `\r?\n\s*--+\s*` regex?

Comment: Please post some more example data.

Comment: If you have paired lines, try `^(.+)\r?\n\h*--+\s*(.+)\r?\n\h*--+` and replace with `$1:$2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace Rows in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531515/replace-rows-in-notepad)

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to find what control characters are there. If it only has `CR and LF` then `\r\n` works fine with regex option selected in replace dialog box.
I have tried this.

To find what control characters are there have a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767545/does-notepad-show-all-hidden-characters)

and then replace it using appropriate regex.

Comment: give me a regex please i have multiple line rows

Comment: Can you post your data after enabling "show all characters" option?