# Replace Rows in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'd like to convert stuff like this:

```
bitte
----------

dream
----------


----------

HD
----------

ready
----------
```

into stuff like this:

```
bitte:dream
HD:ready
```

using a regex. What regex to use? How to put all this rows together?

Answer (score 2):

You may use a regex like

```
^(?:---+\R\s*)*(\w.*)\R---+\R(?:\h*\R)*(\w.*)\R---+$
```

And replace with `$1:$2`.

The `^` matches the line start, `(?:---+\R\s*)*` matches optional delimiter lines before the first non-empty line, `(\w.*)` is Group 1 capturing a word char followed with 0+ chars other than a newline, `\R---+\R` matches a line break followed with 3+ hyphens and a linebreak, `(?:\h*\R)*` matches n number of blank lines, `(\w.*)` (see above) and `\R---+$` matches a linebreak and 3+ hyphens at the end of the line.

[image]

Comment: Why not `-{3,}` instead of `---+`?

Comment: I find `---+` a more readable subpattern. Actually, it can be replaced with `-{n}` by OP with the exact number of hyphens if it is fixed.