# Excel not exporting as textfile correctly

Tags: excel, csv, xls, tex

Isnt being exported in columns as displayed in excel. Trying to export by saving as txt file.

[CSV screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp9ZH.png)

[text file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxvAX.png)

Comment: I guess the problem may be the commas in the prices. But you should show the non-printable characters of the generated text-file: e.g. [Notepad++ can do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767545/does-notepad-show-all-hidden-characters)

Comment: @TmTron im on a mac