# Building my URI using UriBuilder has added a weird charecters %u200b to one of the parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, uribuilder

I am working on an asp.net MVC web application. and i am building a URI to be sent to a web api. but the `UriBuilder` is adding these characters `%u200b` to the beginning of a parameter.
here is my method:-

```
public string Add(string title, string account,string site,string description)
{

  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  using (var client = new WebClient())
  {
    var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
    query["account"] = account;
    query["site"] = site;                     
    query["title"] = title;
    query["description"] = description;
    string apiurl = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiURL"];
    var url = new UriBuilder(apiurl);
    url.Query = query.ToString();
    string xml = client.DownloadString(url.ToString());
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
```

now the `site` parameter will be passed to the method as `Manchester (MAN)` but the final query will have the parameter with `%u200b` added to it as follow:-

```
https://****?account=ABC&site=%u200bManchester+(MAN)&title=ABCDE
```

**so can anyone advice on this please? why the `UriBuilder` is adding `%u200b` to the parameter ??** now the value i am passing is actually a drop-down option, and it is rendered correctly as follow + if i chose another option for the site name i will not face the problem:-

[image]

Comment: `%u200b` is a 'zero width space'

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the reply.. so what does this mean? and why this is being added to the URL parameter,although the drop-down option does not have it...did u get my point

Comment: I think you will find that it is actually in the html if you inspect he source and/or escape it (zero width spaces are not visible in the page). I have seen this issue before where users have cut and pasted html elements (although not sure if that is applicable in your case)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Notepad++ show all hidden characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767545/does-notepad-show-all-hidden-characters)

Comment: @mjwills the result for `site.Length` will be 17

Comment: @johnG, if `site.Length=17`, then that confirms that the extra hidden character is their (otherwise it would be 16)

Comment: You can probably remove it using `.Replace("\u200B", "");` (although that does not address the real issue, which is why its added in the first place)

Comment: @StephenMuecke could the problem be that the value for the site name `Manchester+(MAN)` is added wrongly inside the database? as i me when i tried another option for the site name, i did NOT get this problem.. so seems the problem is specifically on this site name

Comment: @johnG. That seems the most logical reason

Comment: @StephenMuecke so now for me to identify the values which have this charecter, can i query the string which contain this character inside SQL server DB?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138350/how-to-check-for-non-ascii-characters may be of assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have a [zero width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) space in your string (which, as the name suggests, is 'invisible').

Unfortunately `string.Trim` does not remove those characters, as per the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Notes to Callers: The .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and earlier versions
>   maintain an internal list of white-space characters that this method
>   trims. Starting with the .NET Framework 4, the method trims all
>   Unicode white-space characters (that is, characters that produce a
>   true return value when they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace
>   method). Because of this change, the Trim method in the .NET Framework
>   3.5 SP1 and earlier versions removes two characters, ZERO WIDTH SPACE (U+200B) and ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE (U+FEFF), **that the Trim method
>   in the .NET Framework 4and later versions does not remove**. In
>   addition, the Trim method in the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 and earlier
>   versions does not trim three Unicode white-space characters: MONGOLIAN
>   VOWEL SEPARATOR (U+180E), NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE (U+202F), and MEDIUM
>   MATHEMATICAL SPACE (U+205F).

Thus you need to either move to .NET 3.5 SP1 or earlier (not recommended) or use `string.Replace("\u200B", "")` as @StephenMuecke suggested.

Or, even better, fix your source database to remove the errant character there.

*I'd also recommend installing [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to more easily see these hidden characters in future.*

Comment: now my application is on .net 4.5 so not sure why moving to 3.5 SP1 will fix this.. of course i am not planning to do this move to just fix this problem...

Comment: `so not sure why moving to 3.5 SP1 will fix this..` Read the text in yellow above. It explains that the `Trim` method **used** to remove those characters.